# Base64 String when decoded to png is cut off with Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, base64

I'm converting an image that I retrieved from a URL to base 64 using this code.

```
NSURL* imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSData* urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
UIImage* uiImage = [UIImage imageWithData: urlData];
NSData* imageData =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(uiImage);
NSData*  base64 = [imageData base64EncodedDataWithOptions:0];
return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[base64 bytes]];
```

the image url: https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=somedata&size=220x220&margin=0

the generated base64 image.

```
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
```

I figured out the image is only halved because I checked using this tool.

http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

Is there anyway I can generate a base64image String that contains the whole image?

Comment: try by setting image on imageView before encode and check first whether you are getting full mage or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of why it's getting cut off, I suspect you're looking at the base64 string in the debugger, which will truncate it. Actually `NSLog` the string and you'll see it's longer than what you're seeing in the debugger.

A couple of other unrelated observations:

1. You should not use `stringWithUTF8String` with `[base64 bytes]` because the `NSData` will not be null terminated. If you really needed to convert it to a string, you'd use `initWithData` rather than `stringWithUTF8String`:

   ```
   return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:base64 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   ```
2. As others have pointed out, you can bypass the creation of the `NSData` of the `base64` altogether, and create the string directly:

   ```
   return [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
   ```
3. I'm not sure why you're taking the `NSData` from the server and round tripping it through a `UIImage` at all. You can theoretically just encode the data from the server directly:

   ```
   NSURL* imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
   NSData* urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
   return [urlData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
   ```

   The server is already returning you the `NSData` of a PNG representation. You don't need to do that `UIImage` and `UIImagePNGRepresentation` stuff at all. You're actually generating a `PNG` that is considerably larger than the one the server returned to you.
4. I'd advise against using `dataWithContentsOfURL`, because that's a synchronous network call. You probably should use `NSURLSession` and change this to be an asynchronous method.

Comment: Hello! thank you! are indeed correct. the debugger is trimming the base64 I have generated. turns out I just needed to perform an NSLOG to get the full base64. in addition point number 3 is invalid. I've tried that as well but it only gave me a base64 representation of the url itself.

Answer (score 3):

```
    NSURL* imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=somedata&size=220x220&margin=0"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    NSString *base64 = [self encodeToBase64String:image];
```

To convert your image to base64 String use following code:

```
- (NSString *)encodeToBase64String:(UIImage *)image {
    return [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
}
```

That base64 will give you full image. Tested with your given image

Here is base 64 :
  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6d76e3ad852b4879ab097e6a1b3e68a2

Comment: I've tried using the generated result of that. however upon pasting the base64 on this. http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter it fails to render the image.  Here is the base64 https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d00eb963057bf95a8599f344884683d7

Comment: @user962206  see updated answer i used that code and it gives me full image

Answer (score 2):

To convert your `UIImage` into base64 string you can use this code.

```
NSString *base64String =  [UIImagePNGRepresentation(uiImage) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
```

Here is the code.

```
NSURL* imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=somedata&size=220x220&margin=0"];
NSData* urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
UIImage* uiImage = [UIImage imageWithData: urlData];

NSString *base64String =  [UIImagePNGRepresentation(uiImage) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

NSLog(@"%@",base64String);
```

I checked the result string on http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter

Try it, Hope it helps.

Comment: I've tried using that one as well but the  generated result of that. however upon pasting the base64 on this. http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter it fails to render the image.  Here is the base64 https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d00eb963057bf95a8599f344884683d7

Comment: can you share your url plz.

Answer (score 2):

This is working perfectly

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"QRcode.png"];
NSString *base64 = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
NSLog(base64);
```

The printed base64 String can be converted back to image in the URL you provided